# How can a precommit hook tell if it's checking a commit --all?

Tags: git, shell, command-line

How can a git precommit hook tell if the `git commit` command it is preceding is with or without the `-a`/`--all` option?

If it's without `-a` the hook should check only staged changes.

But if it's with `-a` it should check all known files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the staged changes in any case. When that hook is run, it will see 
all changes which are to be committed as being staged. This includes changes 
included because `commit --all` is being used. So this will give the correct 
behaviour in either case without needing to do anything special.

Comment: the diff command I'm using is `git diff-index -p -M HEAD`. How do I get only staged?

Comment: You can get the diff between HEAD and the index using `git diff --cached -p -M`.